# Trouble adding many-to-many relationship to Devise Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a number of functioning many-to-many relationships in my app but I'm having trouble adding this new one (`user_airports` and `home_airports`)!

I'm trying to give my `User` a `home_airports` array, where a `User` has many `home_airports` and an `Airport` has many `Users` (conceptually an airport "belongs to" many users but technically `has_many` of course). I created and migrated the join table and added all the relevant macros to the models. Here's the code:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[facebook]

  has_many :vacations

  has_many :user_airports, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :home_airports, through: :user_airports, source: :airport
end


class UserAirport < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :airport
end


class Airport < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :deal_origins
  has_many :origin_deals, through: :deal_origins, source: :deal

  has_many :deal_destinations
  has_many :destination_deals, through: :deal_destinations, source: :deal

  has_many :user_airports
  has_many :users, through: :user_airports
end

# from my schema.rb
  create_table "user_airports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "airport_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

The `vacations` relationship in `User` works fine (just as an example of something that works).

The `users` relationship in `Airports` actually works fine too. But its inverse does not: with `User`, when I call `user.user_airports` or, more importantly, `user.home_airports`, I get a `NoMethodError`

```
user.home_airports << Airport.first                                                                                               
NoMethodError: undefined method `home_airports' for #<User:0x00007fa7bfc9f630>
```

I'm showing, above, the `deal_origins` and `deal_destinations` relationship in `Airport` because those are many-to-many relationships that work and that appear to be identically implemented to the `User` relationships. (I'm not showing my `Deal` model, but I could if that would be helpful)

The ONLY thing I can imagine is different is that `User` is a `devise` model.

What's going wrong here?

EDIT: 
In response to suggestions in the comments, I stopped my server, exited the console, restarted the server, restarted the console. Still getting the same problem:

```
user.user_airports                                                                                                                
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_airports' for #<User:0x00007fa7bc430e70>
from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/activemodel-5.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'
user.home_airports                                                                                                                
NoMethodError: undefined method `home_airports' for #<User:0x00007fa7bc430e70>
from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/activemodel-5.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'
```

Please let me know if there's any other code you'd like to see, and let me know what you need. Thank you!

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: There is no explanation in the code provided here. I'm guessing that it could be a typographical error or maybe an unsaved file. If you are testing this in the console you have to actually reload any model instances for code changes to take place.

Comment: There is nothing really special about a Devise model except the validations and methods for authentication that Devise provides. It does not alter the way the associations work in your model, so its not a likely explanation.

Comment: @max I know I didn't include much but I think I included what's relevant and that it's self-explanatory. I'll flesh it out a bit.

Comment: I don't really think that will help, the assocation is properly defined. So the problem is not in the code. Have you tried the obvious things like making sure you have saved the file, and restarting the rails console?

Comment: Yes I have saved all the files.